# Renombrar fichero con nombre de variable en Java

Tags: java, archivo, replaceall

soy nuevo en esto y ando buscando la respuesta ya hace unos días.

Quiero nombrar a un fichero con el nombre de la selección de usuario de un JComboBox.

```
archivo = new File (eleccion de JComboBox);
 
        if(archivo.createNewFile()){
                 System.out.println("Archivo creado");
            }
```

Hasta aquí todo sencillo, pero ¿Cómo hago para traer ese valor del JComboBox si esta en otra clase?

Esa es mi duda, le agradezco al que me pueda colaborar.

*Otra cosa si desean responder. Estoy haciendo un programa que almacene datos, pero en un pc que no puedo instalar ningún software por eso decidí que guarde los datos en un .txt o un binario. Existe otra forma de almacenar datos desde java que no sea en una base de datos como MySql o BD en la nube, gracias muchachos.*

Answer (score 0):

creo que lo resolví pero siendo muy redundante. Si alguien tiene una mejor idea se lo agradezco.

Primero creo el archivo:

```
archivo = new File ("fichero.txt");
 
        if(archivo.createNewFile()){
                 System.out.println("Archivo creado");
            }
```

Luego lo renombro de la forma mas sencilla pero creando un método con herencia de la clase de JComboBox:

```
 public void nuevometodo(claseJComboBox nuevodato){

   File oldfile =new File("fichero");
   File newfile =new File(nuevodato.getJComboBox());

           if(oldfile.renameTo(newfile)){
           }
```

Y por ultimo lo cambio de directorio reemplazándolo si ya existe.

```
Path source = Paths.get(""+nuevodato.getJComboBox());
Path newdir = Paths.get("C:\\nuevoDirectorio\\");
Files.move(source, newdir.resolve(source.getFileName()), REPLACE_EXISTING);
```

Y eso es todo, pero como dije, es muy redundante, si alguien conoce la mejor forma de hacer esto se los agradezco.